# Optional Printing in Python

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I use a LOT of print commands as output-error-checking, and as a result (since lots of looping is required) the print outputs become unnecessarily large. Is there a way to write a function to only print when option to print is provided? What I am looking for (and did not work) is this:

```
def custom_print(func, opt=1):
   if opt=1:
      func
   return

custom_print(print("Hello"),0)
```

The above prints "Hello" regardless of argument 0.

Most of the solutions I have checked suggest logging, I am not looking for external log but in-jupyter print since I am not checking code errors, only checking calculation outputs to verify they are what I need them to be. The dream is to have a debug_seed set to 1 when I am in checking mode, then set it to 0 when I know code is accurate and let it run without it cluttering up print outputs.

Edit:

To make the requirement a bit clearer: I am looking for a *generic* function that can take in a print command of multiple types as below:

```
def custom_print(print_command, opt=1)
   # function goes here

# Set seed
debug_mode=1

# print simple phrase
custom_print(print("I want to test my code"), opt=debug_mode)

# print a variable
x = random.randint(5, 10)
custom_print(print("I am 30 but feel {} years older".format(x)), opt=debug_mode)
```

Hope this makes better sense

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this.

```py
def custom_print(message, opt=False):
     if opt:
         print(message)
```

prints `message` when `opt` is `True`.

```
custom_print("Hello", True)
```

prints nothing when `opt` is `False`.

```
custom_print("Hello")
```

Comment: thanks, I am upvoting because you did accurately answered my question, but what about more complex printing such as {}.format() or any variable(s) printing?

Comment: can you give example of what complex things you need to print? (and you didn't up-voted as you said)

Comment: I upvoted, it doesnt show because I dont have enough reputation :( but says it has been recorded.

Comment: No problem. Same thing happened with me before :P